# Fortran 1.0/0.2=4?

Tags: floating-point, integer, fortran, division, floating-accuracy

The code is below:

```
program error
implicit none
real :: l,h
integer :: r
l=1.0
h=0.2
r=l/h
print*,r
end program error
```

The problem is that the answer is 4. When I explicitly divide 1.0 by 0.2, the answer is 5, but when I use symbols, it is 4. In addition, for instance, `1.0/h` and `l/0.2` is also 4. I am really confused.
When I define `r` as real number, the problem is gone; but I need it to be an integer since I am going to use those variables to define a two dimensional array.

Comment: Note that `0.2` is just one name for the rational number 3602879701896397/18014398509481984.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting a problem with rounding of real numbers.

0.2 is not a number that can be represented exactly in binary, so 1/0.2 is also not exactly 5, but can be slightly different.  So, it is possible that it is evaluated to 4.999997 (or something like that).

Second, assignment of a real to an integer truncates, so in your case, it probably happened to be 4 instead of 5.  If you want to assign to the nearest integer, use  `r = nint(l/h)` instead.

Also, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

This has nothing to do with Fortran specifically, it is a general property of floating point arithmetic.  The same thing could happen, for example, in C.

Answer (score 1):

Use the NINT (nearest integer) function to get the nearest integer. The problem with your code is that setting an integer variable to a real number even slightly less than 5 will set it to 4, as demonstrated by the program below. The expression 1.0/0.2 may be computed as slightly less than 5 due to the finite precision of floating point arithmetic.

```
program error
implicit none
real :: l,h
integer :: r
l=1.0
h=0.2
r=nint(l/h)
print*,r ! gives 5
r = 4.99999
print*,r ! gives 4
end program error
```